# dj_rest_auth (jwt) refresh token is empty when login - django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-allauth, dj-rest-auth

im having a trouble with dj_rest_auth jwt package. when i signup for a new account it gives me both access token and refresh token in response, but when i try to login with credentials, all i get is access token, and refresh token is entirely empty!
i configured the code as described in the documentation and the the tutorial that im following.
Any idea about this problem? please let me know.

UPDATE: i just found that refresh token has been set correctly in the response header, but i cant figure out why its not in the response body and its shown empty?!

Settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'dj_rest_auth',
    'dj_rest_auth.registration',

    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'accounts.permissions.IsStaffOrReadOnly',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'dj_rest_auth.jwt_auth.JWTCookieAuthentication',
    ],
}

SITE_ID = 1

REST_AUTH = {
    'USE_JWT': True,
    'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': 'access',
    'JWT_AUTH_REFRESH_COOKIE': 'refresh',
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJ.....",
    "refresh_token": "",
    "user": {
        "pk": 2,
        "username": "test_user_0",
        "email": "test0@mysite.co",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
REST_AUTH = {
    'USE_JWT': True,
    'JWT_AUTH_HTTPONLY':False
}
```

change your rest_auth configuration to this then it should work

[The `AUTH_HTTPONLY` configuration](https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#jwt-auth-httponly) is expressly for disallowing access to the refresh_token for client-side JS. If you want it to only be managed through a cookie, do not change this, if you want to manage your auth state in your JS, you need to change it.

Comment: Fortunately, it fixed with this method. but i wonder if its safe to disable httponly?!

Comment: even though this answer is correct, I am not sure if this is what you'd want to do. would be nice to know if there is a way to get refresh token while httponly = True, or is there any reason dj-rest-auth doing this on purpose

Comment: Did not fix it for me.... :/

Comment: @Morteza I looked it up and edited the answer. If you want to handle auth through JS instead of cookies, it should be fine